# Haskell, mongodb, date 

Tags: mongodb, haskell, bson

How would I insert or auto insert date into mongodb from haskell? What is the best way to convert from mongo date type to haskell data type?

Say, in a situation where I insert blog post records (any haskell web framework) and I want to date stamp every record automatically. How would I go about it? The question is more about type conversion and mongodb date type creation from within haskell driver.

Answer (score 1):

You must create a bson document and store that in mongodb. 
The most elegant is to create a conversion as an instance of bson for your own types.

From the [sources](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/bson/0.2.1/doc/html/Data-Bson.html):

```
instance Val UTCTime where
    val = UTC
    cast' (UTC x) = Just x
    cast' _ = Nothing

instance Val POSIXTime where
    val = UTC . posixSecondsToUTCTime . roundTo (1/1000)
    cast' (UTC x) = Just (utcTimeToPOSIXSeconds x)
    cast' _ = Nothing
```

(or  get the timesstamo for free with timestamp :: ObjectId -> UTCTime)